# Font-Bold of HeaderStyle in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i use this code for gridview format in asp.net:

```
<FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="11px" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" 
    HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FAFAE7" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DAC09E" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E1DB9C" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C2A47B" />
```

i want Font-Bold of HeaderStyle = false:

```
<HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="11px" />
```

but its in browser not false and display font in HeaderStyle is Bold,

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false"
```

its OK :-)